# Returning .NET objects in PowerShell functions

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to get the script below working. The problem I keep running into is the Object being returned is a SystemObject[] instead of a PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.

I wrote the below script with the idea of using this in a larger script by setting a `$out = New-Object PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument` and capturing the return. Unfortunately, this did not work.

After googling for several hours, and finding nothing, I am open to suggestions.

```
Add-Type -Path C:\assemblies\GDI+\PdfSharp.dll

Function mergePdf {
    Param($file1, $file2)

    $output = New-Object PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument
    $PdfReader = [PdfSharp.PDF.IO.PdfReader]
    $PdfDocumentOpenMode = [PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode]


    $input = New-Object PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument
    $input = $PdfReader::Open($file1, $PdfDocumentOpenMode::Import)
    $input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)}
    $input = $PdfReader::Open($file2, $PdfDocumentOpenMode::Import)
    $input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)}

    return $output
}
```

Edit: I changed `$output.pages` to the previous `$output` for clarity, but the script still fails to pass a PdfSharp.Pdf.Pdfdocument object back from the function correctly.

```
$obj = mergePdf temp1.pdf temp2.pdf
$obj.Save("./merged/temp.pdf")
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Save'
.  At line:1 char:10
+ $obj.Save <<<< ("./merged/temp.pdf")
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Save:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

And yet I get:

```
$obj | gm
TypeName: PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
AddPage           Method     PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage AddPage(), PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage Add...
...
Save              Method     System.Void Save(string path), System.Void Save(System.I...
```

Comment: If you want to return a PdfDocument, shouldn't you return `$output` instead of `$output.Pages`?  `Pages` would appear to be an array which is why you get Object[].

Comment: To clarify, I attempted returning several variables. the $output.pages was the last attempt where I tried wrapping. I'll edit for clarity. I had tried $output and it was still returning a system.object[] which did not contain any properties of the PdfDocument.

Comment: system.object[] on v2, seems I get a different error using v3

Comment: Sorry, was transitioning between different computers with different powershell versions, the error is still there, you can disregard the previous comment. Anyways I'm at a loss for why its throwing that error. Not as knowledgeable as some people on this site regarding powershell or dotnet

Comment: Seems the error is related to a seperate issue. This will load the file correctly and return the object however you cannot pass the object back in and have it work. That was the error I was receiving. Apologies. I will start a new thread for the new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are outputting multiple different types via these lines.

```
$input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)}
...
$input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)}
...
return $output
```

Remember that any command/pipeline in a function that doesn't assign to a variable, output to a file or $null or cast to [void] will contribute to the output of the function.  My guess is that $output.AddPage($_) is returning some object - perhaps the page that was added.  Anyway, change those lines to:

```
$input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)} > $null
...
$input.Pages | %{$output.AddPage($_)} > $null
...
$output
```

Also note that the `return` keyword is not required in this case.   You only need to use the return keyword to bail out of a function early.

Comment: That solved the problem. It works perfectly now. I'll have to use > $null from now on for objects that don't return variable. Thank you.

Comment: @Lorek use `> $null` for commands who's output you don't want.

Comment: I know its a little after the fact, that trick worked perfectly in version 3, however I am getting an error in version 2 of powershell which is primarily where it will be used. I have included it as an edit.