# How to return .Net Object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sqlclient

I am trying to write a library Powershell function to return a SQL BulkCopy object which I can then use in various scripts.

Here is my function so far:

```
Function CreateBulkCopyObjectWithTransaction
{
Param
    (
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] $sqlConnection
,   [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction] $sqlTransaction
,   [string] $destinationTable
,   $dataTable
    )

$bulkCopy = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($sqlConnection,[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::Default,$sqlTransaction);
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $destinationTable;
foreach ($dataColumn in $dataTable.Columns) 
{
    $bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($dataColumn.ColumnName, $dataColumn.ColumnName)
}
return $bulkCopy;
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
$dataTable = $eventLogs | OutputToDataTable; #OutputToDataTable is another custom function and works perfectly

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$sqlConnection.Open();

$sqlTransaction = $sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

$bulkCopy = CreateBulkCopyObjectWithTransaction -sqlConnection $sqlConnection -sqlTransaction $sqlTransaction -destinationTable $destinationTable -dataTable $dataTable;

Try
{
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dataTable);
$sqlTransaction.Commit();
}
Catch
{
$sqlTransaction.Rollback();
Write-Host ("Error - " + $_.Exception.Message);
}

$sqlConnection.Close();
```

My problem seems to be that the CreateBulkCopyObjectWithTransaction function does not return a SQLBulkCopy object as I would like, as the error I receive is:

**Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'WriteToServer'.**

I have reviewed various posts, including this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307124/returning-net-objects-in-powershell-functions) about unexpected objects still being in the pipeline, but cannot see that this is the problem as everything has an assignation.

**EDIT:**

Also, this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641714/system-object-doesnt-contain-a-methodnamed-replace) suggested by Ansgar does not address my question as it relates to trying to call a method on an array. I am trying to return a .Net type and call a method on that.

Comment: I do not see any assignment in that line: `$bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add($dataColumn.ColumnName, $dataColumn.ColumnName)`.

Comment: How would I check if that is the issue? I have added a line $bulkCopy.ColumnMappings | Out-Null; but still get the same error. And it is the $bulkCopy object I want to return, with all of it's properties. Thanks.

Comment: Ok have figured it out. @PetSerAl put me along the right lines. I added an Out-Null to the end of the line he mentioned and that has fixed the issue. Thanks.